# Как передвигать точки на canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

На канвасе рисуется линия по точкам, как передвигать уже нарисованные точки?

Работает по сенсорному нажатию.

```
function resize_canvas(){
        canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        imag = document.getElementById("sr200cam");
        if (canvas.width  < imag.width)
        {
            canvas.width  = imag.width;
        }

        if (canvas.height < imag.height)
        {
            canvas.height = imag.height;
        }
    }

    function inits() {
        var touchzone = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        touchzone.addEventListener("touchstart", draws, false);
    }

    function draws() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
        ct = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if(canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillRect (event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY, 5, 5);
            if (i = 0) {
                ct.moveTo(event.touches[0].pageX,event.touches[0].pageY);
            }
                ct.lineTo(event.touches[0].pageX,event.touches[0].pageY);
            ct.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
            ct.stroke();
            str = str + event.touches[0].pageX.toFixed(0) + " " + event.touches[0].pageY.toFixed(0) + ";";
            i++;
        }
    }
```

```
.Dock {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
cursor: default;
overflow: hidden;
color: #808080;
justify-content: space-between;
font-family: arial, helvetica;
}
```

```html
<body onload="inits()">
  <img src="#"/>
  <div class="Dock">
  <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Смотрите, если нажатие произошло на уже существующей точке, то не рисуете новую, а передвигаете существующую. Я так понимаю, что код в вопросе написан не вами?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, код написан мной, с перемещением точки идея такая можно нарисовать линию, и если ошибся или не понравилось как поставил точку то ее зажать и переместить в нужное место, при этом при перемещении точки линия изменяется согласно точке и я не могу придумать как реализовать это.

Comment: Ага, ну раз вами, тогда смотрите, концепция такая. Вы строите объект, в котором описаны все точки на вашем канвас. Там можно сохранить координаты точки, и с кем она связана. Метод draw очищает канвас и рисует  на канвасе точки и линии по вашему объекту. Соответственно, при нажатии проверяете, если клик произошел на точке, то двигаете точку. Не пишу как ответ, потому что это довольно долго писать такой функционал. Кстати, для подобных манипуляций лучше использовать svg.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а как достать из канваса все точки?

Comment: А их не надо оттуда доставать. Надо при клике записывать точки в массив или объект. А потом по объекту рисовать точки!